Is there any significance in the change of the appearance of the buildings?
In the start of the story:

 The gateway to the theme park (Yubaba town?), the first door next to the car, the front of the building was said to be "fake and made of plastic".
 At the end of the story as the leave, the front of the building next to the car, had changed and looked more real (possibly made of concrete) and it was overgrown with vegetation.

Is there any significance to that change? Was it overgrown by time? It looks different

Consequence of a good matte painter. Remember that Chihiro and her parents couldn’t tell the difference either until her father touched it and realized it was plastic and plaster.

lol indeed. but the building structure had also changed. The post needs a before and after screenshot.
